# Mi formulario se envía a una dirección distinta

Tags: html5, formularios, php7

¡Muy buenas!
Estoy realizando una página tratando de no repetir demasiado código, por lo que lo estoy intentando hacer todo con require_once.
Tengo un formulario en html que quiero que me sirva tanto para crear un nuevo producto como para actualizar, le pongo en el action el valor de una variable definida en el php que incluye ese archivo html. El inspector del navegador muestra en el "action" del formulario la dirección que le pongo en dicha variable.
Si pongo "***Controladores/Productos/InsertarProducto_Controlador.php***" me lleva a "***Controladores/Productos/NuevoProducto.php***", el cuál ni siquiera existe. Y si lo pongo con una ***/*** antes de  la palabra ***Controladores***, SÍ me lleva a esa dirección pero pone el mismo mensaje de "***Objeto no localizado***" (se trata de un error 404,  que así es como me lo muestra el xampp), igual que con la página que no existe.

En total sería: la cabecera, el formulario, el archivo que los contiene, el controlador (que a su vez incluye al CRUD_Producto.php, que a su vez incluye la paginación y el Producto_Modelo).
Creo que, de todos modos, con enviar los primeros, es suficiente... Si luego veis que sería importante el CRUD o algún otro, me decís.

Esta es la estructura del proyecto, por si sirviera de algo:

NuevoProducto.php

config/

```
CONSTANTES.php
```

Controladores/

```
Productos/

    InsertarProducto.php
```

css/

```
estilos.css
```

includes/

```
_cabecera.html

_insertar_actualizar.html

_pie_de_pagina.html
```

Modelos/

```
General/

    Conexion.php

    Paginacion.php

Productos/

    CRUD_Productos.php

    Producto_Modelo.php
```

Ahora sí, os  muestro los archivos:

NuevoProducto.php

```
<?php
include 'config/CONSTANTES.php';
$tituloSeccion = "Nuevo Producto";
$formulario_incluido ="insertar";
$nombre_formulario = "formularioInsertarProducto";
$action = INSERTARPRODUCTO_CONTROLADOR;
include_once CABECERA;
include_once FORMULARO_INSERTAR_ACTUALIZAR;
include_once PIE_DE_PAGINA;
```

El texto que escribe la constante es la misma dirección que he puesto(la  del controlador). Incluso  también he  llegado a  escribirlo manualmente, con el mismo resultado. Las constantes las hago así:

```
define('INSERTARPRODUCTO_CONTROLADOR', dirname("Controladores/Productos/InsertarProducto_Controlador.php")."/InsertarProducto_Controlador.php");
```

Y  así con todas las constantes. No sé hacerlas mejor...

_cabecera.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <?php include_once('config/CONSTANTES.php') ?>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $tituloSeccion . " - " . ALG ?></title>
        <link href="<?php echo CSS ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- link(href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet") -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"></script>
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cabecera" id="logo">
            <img src="#" alt="Logotffipo" width="400px" height="200px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="cabecera" id="titulo">
            <h1>¡<?php echo ALG ?>!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cabecera" id="login">
            <p>¡Bienvenid@! ¡Inicia sesión!</p>
            <table>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="emailusuario" id="email-label">Email de usuariod:&nbsp;
                                <input type="email" name="emailusuario" id="emailusuario" required/>
                            </label>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="contrasenausuario" id="contrasena-label">Contraseña:&nbsp;
                                <input type="password" name="contrasenausuario" id="contrasenausuario" required/>
                            </label>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="¡Entrar" name="iniciar_sesion"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Categoría 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Categoría 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Categoría 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

_insertar_actualizar.html

```
    <script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function(){
        new nicEditor().panelInstance('DescripcionLarga');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Ok(){
        nicEditors.findEditor('DescripcionLarga').saveContent();
        document.<?php echo $nombre_formulario ?>.submit();
    }
</script>


<form name="<?php echo $nombre_formulario ?>" id="<?php echo $nombre_formulario ?>" action="<?php echo $action ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="1" class="tabla_nuevo_producto">
        <th colspan="6">AGREGAR UN NUEVO ARTÍCULO</th>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="7" colspan="2">
                ELIGE UNA IMAGEN PRINCIPAL
                <input type="file" name="ImagenPrincipal" id="ImagenPrincipal">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="NombreProducto">Nombre:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="text" name="NombreProducto" id="NombreProducto">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Categoria">Categoría:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="text" name="Categoria" id="Categoria">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="Familia">Familia:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="text" name="Familia" id="Familia">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Subcategoria">Subcategoría:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="text" name="Subcategoria" id="Subcategoria">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
                <label for="DescripcionCorta">Descripción Corta:</label>
                <textarea name="DescripcionCorta" id="DescripcionCorta" rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
                <label for="DescripcionLarga">Descripción Larga</label>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3" colspan="4" align="center" height="329px" valign="top">
                <textarea id="DescripcionLarga" name="DescripcionLarga" rows="25" cols="100"></textarea><br/><br/>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <label>¿Es un elemento destacado?&emsp;</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Destacado" id="Destacado">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Precio">Precio</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="Precio" id="Precio" step="0.10">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="PrecioAnterior">Precio anterior:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="PrecioAnterior" id="PrecioAnterior" step="0.10">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="Stock">Stock:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="Stock" id="Stock">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Precio3U">Precio unitario al comprar 3:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="Precio3U" id="Precio3U" step="0.10">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Precio5U">Precio unitario al comprar 5:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="Precio5U" id="Precio5U" step="0.10">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="Video">Video:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="text" name="Video" id="Video">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Imagen2">Imagen 2:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="file" name="Imagen2" id="Imagen2">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Imagen3">Imagen 3:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="file" name="Imagen3" id="Imagen3">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="Imagen4">Imagen 4:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="file" name="Imagen4" id="Imagen4">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Imagen5">Imagen 5:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="file" name="Imagen5" id="Imagen5">
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="Imagen6">Imagen 6:</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="file" name="Imagen6" id="Imagen6">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <input type="button" name="irPaginaPrincipal" id="irPaginaPrincipal" value="IR A LA PÁGINA PRINCIPAL">
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">
                <input type="button" onclick = "Ok();" value="ENVIAR FORMULARIO" id="nuevoProducto" name="nuevoProducto">
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">
                <input type="reset" name="EnviarFormulario" id="RestablecerFormulario" value="RESTABLECER">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

InsertarProducto_Controlador.php

```
<?php
    include '../../config/CONSTANTES.php';
    require_once '../../' . CRUD_PRODUCTOS;

    try{
        $miCon = new Conexion();//Conecta directo a la base de datos

        $miProducto = new Producto_Modelo();//Instancia del Producto

        //----------IMAGENPRINCIPAL----------/
        if($_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['error']){
            //No se ha podido subir la imagen... ¿Por qué?
            switch ($_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['error']){
                case 1:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor.</p>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo es superior a 2 MB.</p>";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "<p>El envío del archivo se interrumpió.</p>";
                    break;
                case 4: //No se seleccionó ninguna imagen.
                    ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("La IMAGEN PRINCIPAL es obligatoria.");
                        </script>
                    <?php header('location:' . dirname(NuevoProducto.php) . '/NuevoProducto.php');
            }
        } else{//La imagen ya está en el servidor...
            echo "<p>¡La IMAGEN PRINCIPAL se ha subido al servidor!</p>";
            //Comprobamos si efectivamente se ha subido y NO HAY ERRORES
            if(isset($_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['name']) && ($_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
                $destino_ruta = IMAGENES;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['tmp_name'], $destino_ruta.$_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['name']);
                echo  "<p>El archivo <strong>" . $_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['name'] . "</strong> se ha subido subir al directorio de imágenes correctamente.</p>";?>
                <img src="<?php echo IMAGENES . "/" . $_FILES['ImagenPrincipal']['name'] ?>" alt="Imagen Principal">
                <?php
            } else {
                echo "<p>El archivo <strong>no se ha podido subir</strong> al directorio de imágenes.</p>";
            }
        }

    //---...--- En el resto de imágenes, NO se incluye case 4 al no ser obligatorio ---...---
        //---------------IMAGEN2---------------/
        if($_FILES['Imagen2']['error']){
            //No se ha podido subir la imagen... ¿Por qué?
            switch ($_FILES['Imagen2']['error']){
                case 1:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor.</p>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo es superior a 2 MB.</p>";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "<p>El envío del archivo se interrumpió.</p>";
            }
        } else{//La imagen ya está en el servidor...
            echo "<p>¡La IMAGEN 2 se ha subido al servidor!</p>";
            //Comprobamos si efectivamente se ha subido y NO HAY ERRORES
            if(isset($_FILES['Imagen2']['name']) && ($_FILES['Imagen2']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
                $destino_ruta = IMAGENES;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagen2']['tmp_name'], $destino_ruta.$_FILES['Imagen2']['name']);
                echo  "<p>El archivo <strong>" . $_FILES['Imagen2']['name'] . "</strong> se ha subido subir al directorio de imágenes correctamente.</p>";?>
                <img src="<?php echo IMAGENES . "/" . $_FILES['Imagen2']['name'] ?>" alt="Imagen 2">
                <?php
            } else {
                echo "<p>El archivo <strong>no se ha podido subir</strong> al directorio de imágenes.</p>";
            }
        }

        //---------------IMAGEN3---------------/
        if($_FILES['Imagen3']['error']){
            //No se ha podido subir la imagen... ¿Por qué?
            switch ($_FILES['Imagen3']['error']){
                case 1:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor.</p>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo es superior a 2 MB.</p>";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "<p>El envío del archivo se interrumpió.</p>";
            }
        } else{//La imagen ya está en el servidor...
            echo "<p>¡La IMAGEN 3 se ha subido al servidor!</p>";
            //Comprobamos si efectivamente se ha subido y NO HAY ERRORES
            if(isset($_FILES['Imagen3']['name']) && ($_FILES['Imagen3']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
                $destino_ruta = IMAGENES;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagen3']['tmp_name'], $destino_ruta.$_FILES['Imagen3']['name']);
                echo  "<p>El archivo <strong>" . $_FILES['Imagen3']['name'] . "</strong> se ha subido subir al directorio de imágenes correctamente.</p>";?>
                <img src="<?php echo IMAGENES . "/" . $_FILES['Imagen3']['name'] ?>" alt="Imagen 3">
                    <?php
            } else {
                echo "<p>El archivo <strong>no se ha podido subir</strong> al directorio de imágenes.</p>";
            }
        }

        //---------------IMAGEN4---------------/
        if($_FILES['Imagen4']['error']){
            //No se ha podido subir la imagen... ¿Por qué?
            switch ($_FILES['Imagen4']['error']){
                case 1:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor.</p>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo es superior a 2 MB.</p>";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "<p>El envío del archivo se interrumpió.</p>";
            }
        } else{//La imagen ya está en el servidor...
            echo "<p>¡La IMAGEN 4 se ha subido al servidor!</p>";
            //Comprobamos si efectivamente se ha subido y NO HAY ERRORES
            if(isset($_FILES['Imagen4']['name']) && ($_FILES['Imagen4']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
                $destino_ruta = IMAGENES;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagen4']['tmp_name'], $destino_ruta.$_FILES['Imagen4']['name']);
                echo  "<p>El archivo <strong>" . $_FILES['Imagen4']['name'] . "</strong> se ha subido subir al directorio de imágenes correctamente.</p>";?>
                <img src="<?php echo IMAGENES . "/" . $_FILES['Imagen4']['name'] ?>" alt="Imagen 4">
                <?php
            } else {
                echo "<p>El archivo <strong>no se ha podido subir</strong> al directorio de imágenes.</p>";
            }
        }

        //---------------IMAGEN5---------------/
        if($_FILES['Imagen5']['error']){
            //No se ha podido subir la imagen... ¿Por qué?
            switch ($_FILES['Imagen5']['error']){
                case 1:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor.</p>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo es superior a 2 MB.</p>";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "<p>El envío del archivo se interrumpió.</p>";
            }
        } else{//La imagen ya está en el servidor...
            echo "<p>¡La IMAGEN 5 se ha subido al servidor!</p>";
            //Comprobamos si efectivamente se ha subido y NO HAY ERRORES
            if(isset($_FILES['Imagen5']['name']) && ($_FILES['Imagen5']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
                $destino_ruta = IMAGENES;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagen5']['tmp_name'], $destino_ruta.$_FILES['Imagen5']['name']);
                echo  "<p>El archivo <strong>" . $_FILES['Imagen5']['name'] . "</strong> se ha subido subir al directorio de imágenes correctamente.</p>";?>
                <img src="<?php echo IMAGENES . "/" . $_FILES['Imagen5']['name'] ?>" alt="Imagen 5">
                <?php
            } else {
                echo "<p>El archivo <strong>no se ha podido subir</strong> al directorio de imágenes.</p>";
            }
        }

        //---------------IMAGEN6---------------/
        if($_FILES['Imagen6']['error']){
            //No se ha podido subir la imagen... ¿Por qué?
            switch ($_FILES['Imagen6']['error']){
                case 1:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor.</p>";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "<p>El tamaño del archivo es superior a 2 MB.</p>";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "<p>El envío del archivo se interrumpió.</p>";
            }
        } else{//La imagen ya está en el servidor...
            echo "<p>¡La IMAGEN 6 se ha subido al servidor!</p>";
            //Comprobamos si efectivamente se ha subido y NO HAY ERRORES
            if(isset($_FILES['Imagen6']['name']) && ($_FILES['Imagen6']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
                $destino_ruta = IMAGENES;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagen6']['tmp_name'], $destino_ruta.$_FILES['Imagen6']['name']);
                echo  "<p>El archivo <strong>" . $_FILES['Imagen6']['name'] . "</strong> se ha subido subir al directorio de imágenes correctamente.</p>";?>
                <img src="<?php echo IMAGENES . "/" . $_FILES['Imagen6']['name'] ?>" alt="Imagen 6">
                <?php
            } else {
                echo "<p>El archivo <strong>no se ha podido subir</strong> al directorio de imágenes.</p>";
            }
        }

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die("Ha habido un error en la página " . $e->getLine() . "<br>El error es el siguiente: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>");
    } finally {
            $miCon->closeCursor();
            $miCon = null;
    }
```

Y, como os he comentado, si creéis que pueda hacer falta, os puedo incluir el CRUD_Producto.php, que también tiene algún require_once y que, como habéis visto es llamado por el controlador.
¡Infinitas gracias de antemano!
¡Un saludo!

Comment: Sería mejor si abreviaras... me perdí entre tanto código. Si en el `action` pones un archivo y te manda a otro distinto, significa que tienes redirecciones en alguna parte, sea en el mismo archivo PHP que hace de controlador, sea en el `.htaccess`. De todos modos, si lo que quieres es reutilizar código como dices, podrías dirigir todas las peticiones del formulario al mismo archivo, poniendo por ejemplo una clave `action=create`, o `action=read` o `action=update` o `action=delete`, y luego, según la clave, distribuyes el tipo de operación, así tendrías el backend del CRUD en un solo archivo[+]

Comment: [+] Si el CRUD es más amplio y complicado no importa, puedes organizar cada operación: Create, Update, Read, Update  en otros archivos auxiliares o clases o lo que quieras. Luego, en tu archivo que hace de distribuidor de peticiones (que será un único archivo al que mandarás todas las peticiones del formulario identificadas por una clave, como ya dije antes) usas las clases o archivos necesarios para cada caso. Es la manera más simple y organizada de trabajar... Ese archivo podría ser el mismo controlador u otro, eso ya depende de tu contexto.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Justamente el  CRUD_productos es un objeto o clase con esas acciones.En cuanto a lo de la clave,  con  lo  de `action=create` y demás, ¿te  refieres al action  del form  o  a un parámetro llamado action dentro  del  form (`<form  action="Controladores/Productos/NuevoProducto.php?action=create" >`

Comment: En cuanto al `.htaccess`,  no lo he tocado. Por fin he encontrado el  fallo... era  un `../` que  me faltaba en elcontrolador en caso  de que ciertos  campos no estén rellenados. ¡Infinitas gracias!

Comment: Sí, me refiero a mandar con los datos un `action=....` con el tipo de acción específica  y luego en el servidor puedes hacer algo como: `$mAction=$_POST["action"];` y luego por medio de un `switch` o de otro modo distribuyes desde un solo sitio las diferentes operaciones del CRUD, sabiendo que en `$mAction` vas a tener `create, read, update, delete`  según el caso.

Comment: ¡Estupendo! Infinitas gracias! :)